# Const command not found

Tags: plugins, command, nagios

I am setting up Nagios `check_hpjd` plugin, but it doesn't recognize "const" command.

I am using Nagios 4.x on a Linux server, and was setting up some network printers to monitor and decided to add `check_hpjd` plugin, for more detailed information, but unfortunately it started to give me:

> /libexec/check_hpjd: line 1: const: command not found.

I think it is pointless to copy the whole `check_hpjd` plugin code here, I just copy the first line here, the system gave me error on:

```
const char *option_summary = "-H host [-C community]\n";
```

Should I define the const character somehow or how can I fix it, tried to look from several sources on web aswell, but there is very little info about it unfortunately.

Comment: Can you share link to the script?

Comment: Of course, it can be found from here: https://github.com/monitoring-plugins/monitoring-plugins/blob/master/plugins/check_hpjd.c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using source code of that plugin, so the behavior is correct... You need use builded version, like [here](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/okey-x86_64/nagios-plugins-hpjd-2.1.1-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm.html) for Centos7/RHEL7.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was able to get it to work, now have some timeout issues with the printers IP, but I hope I can fix it now on my own! Thank you once again! :)